# temporarily highlighting current line

Tags: highlighting

The minor mode `global-hl-line` highlights the current line "permanently" (until it is disabled).

Instead, I would prefer a command which highlights the current line for, say, one second.

Has anybody done this?

Comment: See:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can use command `flash-line-highlight` (e.g., bind it to a key) to highlight the current line for `line-show-period` seconds (which you can customize).  This is in library [`hl-line+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hl-line%2b.el). See [Highlight Current Line](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine#HlLinePlus).
- If you want to highlight both the line and the column temporarily then you can use command `flash-crosshairs` (bind it to a key).  This is in library [`crosshairs.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/crosshairs.el). See [Crosshair Highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting).

Comment: Someone want to explain the downvote?